# I get a warning saying: is not an activity subclass or alias

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

[What does the icon next to MapsActivity mean?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/818JA.png)

When I run the app, it says MapsActivity is not an Activity subclass or alias. 
That is my mainfest?

```
    <application

        <activity android:name=".MapsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to make MapsActivity extend Activity (or preferably AppCompatActivity). Though I'm not sure how you even coded any lifecycle functions without doing that. Can you post the code for MapsActivity?